# How do I view the commits added to the branch I'm tracking?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a local Git repository that I haven't updated in a few days. I want to update to the latest code and do some work. Before I do that though I'd like to gain a rough idea of what changes have been made to that codebase since I last worked on it.

So I do a git fetch to get all subsequent commits. Now I want to view a log of my local branch and the remote branch I'm tracking, ideally in TortoiseGit (or some other Git UI) so I can actually examine the file changes in each commit, and by 'examine the file changes' I don't mean spew reams of diff patch syntax to the console.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a fetch of the remtoe changes in TortoiseGit using "Git Fetch".

Then go to the "Log" and activate "Show all branches" (or click on the upper left blue label to select the branches you want to see). Then you can see your local branch and the remotely pushed commits.

Comment: That's what I tried to start with. The problem with doing that though is that it also shows all the feature branches currently in the repo many of which will appear between the local develop and origin/develop branches with no effective way of determining which of the commits between origin/develop and develop are on the origin/develop branch and which are on the various feature branches.

Comment: Have you tried just selecting the two branches you want to compare as I described?

Comment: Yes. When I try the command 'Show all branches' the log includes all the feature branches too, and if I click on the branch label in the Browse References dialog I do not seem to be able to select both 'develop' and 'origin/develop' together, although I _can_ select two branches under heads or remotes/origin.

Comment: If I select origin/master and origin/develop it shows both branches, I can find no way to select heads/develop and origin/develop though, even if I manually type any form of those paths into the filter textbox it ignores them.

Comment: In the "Browse References" dialog you can go one level up ("refs") on the left side and then select the local branch and the remote branch on the right. if you only want to see only the commits in between the two branches select the ".." operator (i.e., "branch1..branch2")

Comment: Ahh, that's how you do it! You have to have 'Show nested refs' ticked to do this which is unticked by default, but that's really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are currently on the Develop branch, in the TortoiseGit log view click the branch name 'develop' in the top left.

The 'Browse References' dialog will open, in the ref tree on the left of that dialog select the node refs/remotes/origin/develop and click Ok to close the dialog.

The log will now update to show the origin/develop branch, however since your local develop branch is tracking this remote branch your develop branch is simply a tag pointing to one of the commits in this remote branch, which you will see as the bolded log entry with the 'develop' branch tag, followed by all the subsequent commits to the origin/develop branch right up to the origin/develop branch tag at the top.

After browsing the subsequent commits (and assuming you have no uncommitted changes) you can update your tracking branch with the latest remote commits by right clicking the topmost commit which will have the branch tags origin/head,origin/develop and selecting 'merge to develop' which will perform a fast forward merge of the outstanding commits into your local 'develop' branch (in effect just moving the local 'develop' branch tag to the same changeset as the origin/develop branch).